# Firebase Facebook Login Bug

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I'm using Firebase with Facebook login in my android app. But some user's email address "—" looks like.
[image]

is this an error?

Comment: Debug your code of Facebook login, and check that you received email from Facebook. Due to privacy policy on Facebook, for some user, Facebook doesn't return his email id when they allow to login.

Comment: Did you added email permission for Facebook login?

Comment: Yes I'm added "public_profile" and "email"